# Looping through complex object with a variable in the variable name

Tags: powershell

I have a complex object that is populated from a JSON string.

I'm trying to loop through a nested object that has a variable in the name itself.

So if I do a **Write-Host $aaa.bbb.ccc1ccc.ddd** I get a valid object back.
   if I do a **Write-Host $aaa.bbb.ccc2ccc.ddd** I get a valid object back.

If I set **$i = 1** and I do

**Write-Host $aaa.bbb.ccc$($i)ccc.ddd** it will of course fail.

If I try **get-variable -valueonly -name "aaa.bbb.ccc$($i)ccc.ddd"** 
I get an error: Cannot find a variable with the name 'aaa.bbb.ccc1ccc.ddd'

to be honest I can't even do a **get-variable -valueonly -name "aaa.bbb"**

There are other objects like aaa.bbb.dddd. that I don't want.

If $i is [1..100]  can someone show me how to loop through this object?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `.` reference operator, since version 3.0, you can substitute an expandable string for any member reference:

```
$aaa.bbb."ccc${i}ccc".ddd
```

so in your example you could do:

```
1..2 |ForEach-Object { $aaa.bbb."ccc${i}ccc".ddd }
```

Comment: Oh, thank you.  I've been beating my head against my keyboard for hours on this one.